# We were unable to refresh one or more data connections in this workbook

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, powerpivot

I use `SharePoint 2013` and `Excel Services` and `PoverPivot Services`.

I have a `Pover Pivot` report . When I see this in `SharePoint` and I want refresh my data from `Data` menu,

[image]

I get this error :

```
External Data Refresh Failed
An error occurred while working on the Data Model in the workbook. Please try again. 

We were unable to refresh one or more data connections in this workbook. 
The following connections failed to refresh:
```

[image]

I fond this [Link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/excel_services__powerpivot_for_sharepoint_support_blog/archive/2013/02/01/powerpivot-2013-refreshing-in-the-browser.aspx) but this not work.

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same issue.
In my case my powerpivot datamodel was pointing among Others also to a second Excel file, stored in a DocumentLibray.

Once you have followed all steps in the article below:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj879294.aspx

You should enable VERBOSE log for "PowerPivot Service" category.
Trigger a manual refresh in order to produce the log output.

I you find this error in the log:
*The provider 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' is not registered.*
This is related to missing x64 OLEDB driver.

In my case I had Office 2013 x32 installed in the SharePoint server, and that's the point.
SharePoint is x64, so it could not load the proper OleDB driver (x64) which I downloaded and installed from:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255
(it is the same driver for Office 2010 and 2013 actually).

Comment: It not work for me. I Installed Office 2013 x32 but from your link I installed OleDB driver (x64) . but now my problem is exist yet.